# Crash when starting Traefik in cluster mode

Tags: traefik

I recently wanted to change from a one-node Traefik install (that was using a configuration file), to a 3-node Traefik cluster.

Following the docs, I uploaded the configuration:

```
$ traefik storeconfig
```

It displayed no error, and checking the Consul KV, keys are there.

But when launching Traefik in cluster mode, I get a segmentation fault:

```
$ traefik --cluster=true -d

INFO[0001] Using TOML configuration file /etc/traefik/traefik.toml
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x83500e]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/containous/traefik/cluster.NewLeadership(0x2e08560, 0xc420557840, 0xc4202a1340, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/containous/traefik/cluster/leadership.go:28 +0x6e
github.com/containous/traefik/server.NewServer(0x2540be400, 0x100, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc42035b930, 0x5, 0xc4205ef740, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/containous/traefik/server/server.go:105 +0x63e
main.run(0xc4205678c0)
    /go/src/github.com/containous/traefik/cmd/traefik/traefik.go:307 +0x6f6
main.main.func1(0xc42016cdc0, 0xc4202b31a0)
    /go/src/github.com/containous/traefik/cmd/traefik/traefik.go:61 +0xd9
github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/github.com/containous/staert.(*Staert).Run(0xc4206c1f30, 0x1aa1940, 0xc420496300)
    /go/src/github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/github.com/containous/staert/staert.go:83 +0x2e
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/containous/traefik/cmd/traefik/traefik.go:218 +0x1bf1
```

I've tried with latest stable, 1.3.7 and the 1.4.0-rc1 releases, both show the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your traefik.toml is incorrect and does not have the correct configuration for your consul backend.

try using this as your command or modify the consul section of the config @ /etc/traefik/traefik.toml

traefik --consul --consul.endpoint=YOURENDPOINTHERE --cluster=true -d

make sure to refer to this
https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/consul/

Comment: I did try that originally, but that lead to exactly the same problem. Weird thing is, I can start all Traefik instances without --cluster, and they still will share the same ACME certificates and configuration, albeit with an occasional locking issue.

So not sure about the cluster flag, can not even find it in the docs now. Maybe it is no longer necessary?